# OpsManager mongodb deployment issue adding PLAIN auth

Tags: mongodb, devops

I'm trying to enable PLAIN authentication security over a mongodb replica shard managed with OpsManager following their documentation https://docs.opsmanager.mongodb.com/v4.0/tutorial/enable-ldap-authentication-for-group/ .

The issue I'm facing is at the automation-agent trying to get mongoS status while restarting after enabling security. Please see the error output below:

```
<mongos_5> [09:18:19.711] Failed to compute states : 
<mongos_5> [09:18:19.711] Error calling ComputeState : <mongos_5> [09:18:19.632] Error getting current config from running mongo using conn params = mongos01:27017 (local=false) : 
<mongos_5> [09:18:19.632] Error getting pid for mongos01:27017 (local=false) : 
<mongos_5> [09:18:19.632] Error running command for runCommandWithTimeout(dbName=admin, cmd=[{serverStatus 1} {locks false} {recordStats false}]) : 
result={"$clusterTime":{"clusterTime":6808443558471663617,"signature": {"hash":"e44BxV30B7dTpampo4VZsVuio7E=","keyId":6808441655801151517}},"code":13,"codeName":"Unauthorized", 
"errmsg":"command serverStatus requires authentication","ok":0,"operationTime":6808443558471663617} connection=&{mongos01:27017 (local=false) 2 true 0xc4207b21a0 2020-03-26 09:18:19.627337419 +0000 UTC 0xc4207bdef0 <nil> } 
identityUsed= : command serverStatus requires authentication
```

I noticed that even if opsmanager is not able to get the status the security was enabled successfully and PLAIN authentication mechanism works but the status hangs at

```
    Start the process   ... Start MongoDB process
```

I tried this over the API following mongodb-labs repo https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mms-api-examples/blob/master/automation/api_usage_example/configs/security_ldap_cluster.json but also manually following mongodb docs but everytime I'm facing the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all I enabled LDAP(PLAIN) only for mongo in mongoconfig file (see below the ops manager API snippet call example), and avoid enable in opsmanager for the agents also.

```
{
        "args2_6": {
            "net": {
                "port": 28001
            },
            "replication": {
                "replSetName": "rs0"
            },
            "storage": {
                "dbPath": "/data/mongo"
            },
            "systemLog": {
                "destination": "file",
                "path": "/data/mongo/mongodb.log"
            },
            "security": {
                "authorization": "enabled"
            },
            "setParameter": {
                "saslauthdPath": "",
                "authenticationMechanisms": "PLAIN,MONGO-CR,SCRAM-SHA-256",
            }
        }, ...
```